# Expo react native Android Deep linking not working

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking

I am trying to implement a deep link on Android ( Similar to iOS universal link). Please find below the SDK details.

SDK Version: 37.0.12
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all):

Android
app.json contains an intent filter as suggested

```
"intentFilters": [
    {
      "action": "VIEW",
      "data": [
        {
          "scheme": "https",
          "host": "**************",
          "pathPrefix": "/records"
        }
      ],
      "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
    }
  ]
```

below is app.js code.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator()

function App() {
 const linking = { prefixes: ['*******','exps://********'] }

return (
  <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  )
 }
```

export default App

and the server contains asset links hosted on well-known/assetlinks.json

```
[
 {
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
   "target": {
  "namespace": "android_app",
  "package_name": "************",
  "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [ "5C:AF:56:11:A5:3C:82:A7:9D:18:23:6E:CC:67:08:16**********" 
  ]
  }
 }
]
```

The app runs as expected however, Deep link doesn’t seem to work.

am I missing something? Any leads/suggestion/input will be highly appreciated

Regards,
H

Comment: Hello! How did you manage it?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, were you able to solve it?